# filter taking to much time in posgresdb on gender field

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have one table with 100M plus rows which looks like this

```
Create table member (
  id bigint,
  gender text,
  //..other fields
  primary key (id)
);
```

Now the **gender** field has two possible value **'M'** or **'F'**

Whenever I am using the gender field then it's taking to much time I have indexes on other fields like id, member details, mobile number

```
select 
count(1) filter (where mod.is_active and m.gender = 'M') as male,
count(1) filter (where mod.is_active and m.gender = 'F') as female
from member_other_details mod
inner join member m on m.id = mod.member_id
```

This query is taking hrs to complete

How can I optimize this?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Note that `count(*)` will actually be slightly faster than `count(1)`

Comment: Indexes won't really help with that query because you are reading all rows from both tables. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. Currently you are counting the number of _details_ for male and female members. If you only want to get the count of male or female _members_ then you should remove the join which will certainly speed this up.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please check now i have modified

Answer (score 1):

Personnally i would execute this query

```
select m.gender,count(*)
from member_other_details mod inner join member m on m.id = mod.member_id
where mod.is_active
group by m.gender
```